# Ubuntu on Chromebook

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, chromebook

So, I recently bought a Toshiba Chromebook 2 and have I've tried everything to wipe Chrome Os off the SSD or to "Legacy Dual Boot" to run a full blown Linux Distro. So in my efforts to get a full Linux Distro I created a partition which I have no idea how to get rid of. So, if anyone knows how to delete the partition or how to install a full OS I would love some input. 
Thanks

Comment: To replace ChromeOS with Linux you need to enable SEA-BIOS in coreboot. As far as I know, this is not yet possible in Toshiba Chromebook 2.  Your best course of action may be to reinstall the ChromeOS. This probably will delete any extra partitions you have created.

Answer (score 0):

user68186 is right you need to flash your chromebook with a modified bios. Thanks to John's hard work you can now download it from his [website](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/).

The main steps are:

- Enable developer mode on your chromebook
- Disable write-protect so that you can write to the BIOS
- Flash the BIOS with the modified version downloaded from John's site
- Boot your chromebook from a live Ubuntu USB drive and
  install in the normal way (it's a good idea to wipe all the chrome OS
  partitions).

If you need a step by step process for this, see my post on [wiping Chrome OS and installing Ubuntu](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/chromebook/install-ubuntu-on-the-toshiba-chromebook-2-in-5-steps).